# Why does this Python function only have one output?

Tags: python, if-statement, output

I have this very simple Python function, but there is one part I am confused about. The function is called bigger and it takes two numbers as inputs and outputs the bigger number. (I could only use if statements, no elses)

Here's the code:

```
def bigger(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return x
    return y
```

I would think that this code would return `y` if `y` is bigger (which it does), but it would return `x` and `y` if `x` is bigger (it only returns `x`). Why does it only return one output? Can Python functions only have one output?

Comment: It is returning y if y is bigger.

Comment: Return exists the function.

Comment: A function can only return once each time it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def bigger(x, y):
    if x > y:
        # when x>y, x will be returned and 'return y' in the last line will not be executed.
        return x
    # only if x<y, this line will be executed.
    return y
```

Answer (score 4):

The `return` statement not only returns a value, but also terminates the current function and returns control to the calling function. So, this function will only return a single value. In my opinion it would be slightly more clear to write this:

```
def bigger(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return x
    else:
        return y
```

but the result would not differ.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was the misunderstanding. `return` works the same in most languages -- once you hit it, the function is over and control reverts to the function that called it. I think there are some languages where the concept of passing information back to the caller (return a value) and the concept of terminating a function (return control) are separate, but Python isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Python functions can only return one value. It would be possible to return both x and y as a tuple, but the way this function is set up, it will return a single value and then exit the function.

Answer (score 1):

In a Python function, when a `return` statement is encountered, execution of that function is terminated.  Execution context then goes back to the context that called the function.

So, even though you see two `return` statements, if that first one is encountered (as a result of x being bigger than y), nothing else in the function runs.

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#return

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def bigger(x, y):
if x > y:
    a=(x,y)
    # or a=[x,y]
    return a
return y
```

This way it will return x and y if x is bigger, but y if y is bigger. I assume this was your question?

The reason for this is that return gives back that 1 value, then exits the function. So it would leave 
the function bigger(x,y) as soon as it hits that return. If you want to return both x and y, you can do so with a tuple, list, whatever you want, as I did with a tuple.

Comment: That is true, I was just trying to make it simple/clear by assigning the value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Python functions only returns one value.

You can try,

```
def bigger(x, y):

    #this is optional: value = None
    if x > y:
        value = x
    else:
        value = y
    return value
```